# pthreads SIGHUP on Simple Linux Timer

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads

Running on:

```
mehoggan@mehoggan-laptop:~/Code/svn_playground/C++/timer/timer0$ uname -a
Linux mehoggan-laptop 2.6.32-37-generic #81-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 20:32:42 UTC 2011 x86_64 GNU/Linux
mehoggan@mehoggan-laptop:~/Code/svn_playground/C++/timer/timer0$ cat /etc/*release*
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=10.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=lucid
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS"
mehoggan@mehoggan-laptop:~/Code/svn_playground/C++/timer/timer0$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

mehoggan@mehoggan-laptop:~/Code/svn_playground/C++/timer/timer0$
```

I am trying to write a timer class that runs on a background thread and uses gettimeofday(3) function plus a user specified callback function. The usage of this will be in a OpenGL app I am in the process of porting from Windows to Linux.

When I run this code (see below). My threads get hung up when running in release mode. However, when I step through the code with a debugger everything seems to work just fine. This indicates a timing issue to me. I might be wrong about this since I am just now learning how to use threads. Could someone help me understand why my threaded application is getting this signal from the OS?

There are two place you can get the code, you can download it from my trac site:
[Trac Site](http://matthewh.me/playground/browser/branches/C++/timer/timer0)

### Or you can just copy and paste:

MAIN.CPP

```
#include "TimerManager.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/time.h>

std::ofstream out;

void func1(int id)
{
  struct timeval l_tv;
  gettimeofday(&l_tv, NULL);
  std::cout << "I was called (1) @ " << l_tv.tv_usec << std::endl;
  out.flush();
}

void func2(int id)
{
  struct timeval l_tv;
  gettimeofday(&l_tv, NULL);
  std::cout << "I was called (2) @ " << l_tv.tv_usec << std::endl;
  out.flush();
}

int main(int, char *[])
{
  out.open("/home/mehoggan/Desktop/log.log");

  TimerManager t;
  t.addTimer(1000000 * 10, func1);
  t.addTimer(1000000 * 20, func2);
  t.start();
  while(true) {
    sleep(1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

```
#ifndef TIMERMANAGER_H_
#define TIMERMANAGER_H_

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <list>

extern "C" {
  void *create_pthread(void *data);
}

class TimerManager {
public:
  TimerManager();
  ~TimerManager();
  void start();
  void stop();
  void addTimer(long usec, void (*callback)(int id));
private:
  class Timer  
  {
  public:
    Timer(long usec, void (*callback)(int)) :
      duration(usec),
      callback(callback),
      start(0)
    {      
    }
    bool operator ==(Timer other)
    {
      if ((this->callback == other.callback) && (this->duration == other.duration)) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
    void operator =(Timer other)
    {
      duration = other.duration;
      callback = other.callback;
      start = other.start;
    }
    suseconds_t duration;
    void (*callback)(int);
    suseconds_t start;
  };
  std::list<Timer> m_timers;
  Timer setUpTimer(long micro_duration, void (*callback)(int id));
  friend void *create_pthread(void *data);
  void run();
  bool m_bRunning;
  bool m_bGo;
  long m_lMinSleep;
  pthread_t m_tTimerThread;
  pthread_cond_t m_tGoLockCondition;
  pthread_mutex_t m_tGoLock;
};

#endif
```

---

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include "TimerManager.h"

extern "C" void *create_pthread(void *data)
{
  TimerManager *thread_timer_manager = static_cast<TimerManager *>(data);
  thread_timer_manager->run();
  return data;
}

TimerManager::TimerManager() :
  m_bRunning(false),
  m_bGo(false),
  m_lMinSleep(0)
{
  int mutex_creation = pthread_mutex_init(&m_tGoLock, NULL);
  if(mutex_creation != 0) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to create mutex" << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  int mutex_cond_creation = pthread_cond_init(&m_tGoLockCondition, NULL);
  if(mutex_cond_creation != 0) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to create condition mutex" << std::endl;
    return;
  }

  int thread_creation = pthread_create(&m_tTimerThread, NULL, create_pthread, this);
  if(thread_creation != 0) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to create thread" << std::endl;
    return;
  }
  m_bRunning = true;
}

TimerManager::~TimerManager() 
{
  m_bRunning = false;
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&m_tGoLock);
  void *result;
  pthread_join(m_tTimerThread, &result);
}

void TimerManager::run() 
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&m_tGoLock);
  while(m_bRunning) {
    while (!m_bGo) {
      pthread_cond_wait(&m_tGoLockCondition, &m_tGoLock);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_tGoLock);
    if (!m_bRunning) {
      break;
    }
    pthread_detach(m_tTimerThread);

    struct timeval l_tv;
    sleep(std::max(0l, m_lMinSleep));
    gettimeofday(&l_tv, NULL);
    m_lMinSleep = 0;
    long l_lMin = 0;
    for(std::list<Timer>::iterator it = m_timers.begin(); it != m_timers.end(); ++it) {
      TimerManager::Timer l_oTimer = *it;
      long elapsed_time = ((l_tv.tv_sec * 1000000 + l_tv.tv_usec) - (l_oTimer.start));
      l_lMin = elapsed_time - l_oTimer.duration;
      if (elapsed_time >= l_oTimer.duration) {
        l_lMin = l_oTimer.duration;
        l_oTimer.callback(0);
        gettimeofday(&l_tv, NULL);
        it->start = (l_tv.tv_sec * 1000000) + l_tv.tv_usec;
      }
      m_lMinSleep = std::min(m_lMinSleep, l_lMin);
    }
  }
}

void TimerManager::start()
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&m_tGoLock);
  m_bGo = true;
  pthread_cond_signal(&m_tGoLockCondition);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_tGoLock);
}

void TimerManager::stop() 
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&m_tGoLock);
  m_bGo = false;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_tGoLock);
}

TimerManager::Timer TimerManager::setUpTimer(long micro_duration, void (*callback)(int id))
{
  struct timeval l_tv;
  gettimeofday(&l_tv, NULL);
  Timer l_oTimer(micro_duration, callback);
  l_oTimer.start = (l_tv.tv_sec * 1000000) + l_tv.tv_usec;
  return l_oTimer;
}

void TimerManager::addTimer(long usec, void (*callback)(int id)) 
{
  Timer insert = setUpTimer(usec, callback);
  typedef std::list<Timer>::iterator li;
  m_timers.push_back(insert);
}
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your destructor is definitely broken. You can't destroy a mutex while another thread might be using it. And you can't modify `m_bRunning` while another thread might be accessing it. You want:

```
TimerManager::~TimerManager() 
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&m_tGoLock);
  m_bRunning = false;
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&m_tGoLock);
  void *result;
  pthread_join(m_tTimerThread, &result);
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&m_tGoLock);
}
```

You have a lot of concurrency bugs. For example,  your `addTimer` function modifies the shared `m_timers` structure without holding a mutex.

Comment: I added in the fixes I saw appropriate and have commmited the changes, however the program is still locking. Any suggestions on how to debug without a debugger? Since the debugger allows things to work as I am stepping through the code.

Comment: Let it lock and then attach the debugger to see where it's locked.

Comment: OMFG it works. I had the timer set to 10 sec and was to impatient to wait so I thought things locked. Thanks for your help. I should go to sleep before I hurt myself.